# Phonegap: "standalone" app with node.js

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, redis

I want to write a Phonegap app with a local node.js server.
Is this possible?
With node.js i can use a redis-client and sdl functionality.

This is [Tim Caswalls talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uscdtg6nyqQ) about node.js and phonegap but i can not find any more info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be looking into these

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

http://appjs.com/

here is an example
have a look at clipconverter.cc desktop
it uses appjs as far as i know

Comment: Please read [answer] and provide informations that will make it so that your answer keeps being useful even if the links die.